# Spring Cloug GCP 'function' with name '' must not be null

Tags: spring-boot, google-cloud-platform, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-function

I'm trying to develop a spring cloud application with functions and google cloud. Right now I can start the webservice using mvn function:run like the samples suggest. But I run into the following error

```
Failed to execute org.springframework.cloud.function.adapter.gcp.GcfJarLauncher
   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 'function' with name '' must not be null
```

Here's my class

```
@Component
open class UserFunctions: Supplier<UserDto?>, Consumer<UserDto> {
    @Autowired
    lateinit var userService: UserService

    override fun get(): UserDto? {
        val context = SecurityContextHolder.getContext()
        return userService.getUserByEmail(context.authentication.name)
    }

    override fun accept(userDto: UserDto) {
        userService.saveUser(userDto, SecurityContextHolder.getContext().authentication.name)
    }
}
```

Here's my config

```
spring:
  config:
    name: local
  ....
  cloud:
    function:
      web:
        path: /api/v1/
      definition: userfunctions
    gcp:
      firestore:
        emulator:
          enabled: false
        enabled: false
```

I've tried not having the path, calling definition UserFunction userFunctions and calling HTTP://localhost:8080:/ /api/v1/ api/v1/userFunctions etc...

Comment: Are you able to deploy the [following application](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-function/tree/master/spring-cloud-function-samples/function-sample-gcp-http)? I can see that the deployment of SpringBoot applications in Cloud Functions is reliant on the following [adapter](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-function/reference/html/gcp.html) (which is in Alpha and might have issues) in order to create the deployable JAR file.

Comment: By checking the code [here](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-function/tree/master/spring-cloud-function-adapters/spring-cloud-function-adapter-gcp) I'm not sure as to where exactly is the adapter expecting to read the Cloud Function's name.

Comment: So I ended up giving up this, I was able to get a sample app working. Looking at the docs placing something under the functions package would pick it up. But I tried everything I could, and a simple app would work.

Comment: I am also getting this error. I followed https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-function/blob/main/spring-cloud-function-samples/function-sample-gcp-http, added few functions with @Bean. Then running locally using mvn function:run but when I access it in browser using http://localhost:8080/<my-bean-name> the in console getting above error.

Comment: I had the same issue and I was able to fix it by removing spring-cloud-function-web dependency and using only spring-cloud-function-context and spring-cloud-function-adapter-gcp